# WPF Changing the user interface language at runtime

Tags: wpf

I want to change my user interface language at run time. what is the best approach to do this?

Regards
Raju

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Localization.aspx

Uses a XAML markup extension and resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this document](http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/releases/view/29389), it describes various approaches to implement localization. Using a solution such as markup extensions or attached properties, you should be able to change the language at runtime

Answer (score 0):

If you can carry extra files with your software, you could probably go for XML files, each files containing a particular language. The other option is probably using a database for storing the words.

Comment: How do i change the language of UI elements? I have few text boxes on my page. I want to change the text in the text boxes at run time.How can i do that?

Comment: It's a big lecture, but I suggest taking a look at what Thomas Levesque has posted. This document seem pretty complete to me.