# Dynamic language selecting

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to create a dynamic language "ListView" where the user can select a language and after that the language will change and will stay/save.

Now I have this code:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return this._items; }
}
```

//add Language(Items) in the ListView

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    Items.Add("English");
    Items.Add("German");
    Items.Add("French");
    Items.Add("Mandarin");
    Items.Add("Spanish");
}
```

//ListView select items

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ClickedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "English":
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-US";
    break;

        case "German":
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "de-DE";
    break;

        case "French":
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr-FR";
    break;

        case "Mandarin":
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "zh-Hans";
    break;

        case "Spanish":
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "sp-SP";
    break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

//In this button will be many if else statements ...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    //ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "fr"; 
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Shell));
}
```

//XAML looks like this

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}" Height="500" Width="200" Margin="500,200,500,200" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Adding and selecting works but the saving not, i mean i havent programm it till end. Is there a solution to get the language resources like "Strings/de-De/resources.rew" and fill it in the list and by selecting save it in a dynmic way?

Comment: So you show some basic binding and event handling and then suddenly ask [how to switch language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461772/1997232)? Btw, setting `PrimaryLanguageOverride` can be one liner if you use `Dictionary<string,string>` (see [binding to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44147091/1997232)) to store "en-US" as key and "English" as value.

Comment: i just show my code in a hard coding way and want to get it dynamically , so where is the problem?

Comment: What is the general problem you're trying to solve? Typically the user will have their preferred languages set in Settings and the app should just follow those preferences.

Comment: its a embedded application device with windows iot, so there is no Settings. This code is running but i dont want the switch cases and the Items Adding manually. I just want to add in Strings/ some languages resources and the Items adding by itself and shows up in the ListView.Just more dynamic than this hard coding.Everytime i add a resource file i have to add it in the ListView and make a switch case.. thats weird. Something like that http://edi.wang/post/2017/9/9/windows-10-uwp-switching-language but i dont get the tutorial.